# org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException in Neo4j

Tags: eclipse, neo4j

I've been using neo4j 1.9 RC1 for the past two months. Yesterday, after an eclipse crash I started having this this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@bf5743' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:282)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:90)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:75)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:60)
at fr.inria.atlanmod.neo4emf.drivers.impl.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:44)
at fr.inria.atlanmod.neo4emf.drivers.impl.PersistenceServiceFactory.createPersistenceService(PersistenceServiceFactory.java:27)
at fr.inria.atlanmod.neo4emf.drivers.impl.PersistenceManager.<init>(PersistenceManager.java:80)
at fr.inria.atlanmod.neo4emf.impl.Neo4emfResource.<init>(Neo4emfResource.java:58)
at fr.inria.atlanmod.neo4emf.impl.Neo4emfResourceFactory.createResource(Neo4emfResourceFactory.java:58)
at main.JDTASTMain.main(JDTASTMain.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@bf5743' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:260)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to start TM, no active tx log file found but found either tm_tx_log.1 or tm_tx_log.2 file, please set one of them as active or remove them.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:738)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.start(TxManager.java:138)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
... 11 more
```

I am running it with Java 1.7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your data directory is corrupt. There is already a suggestion printed to the log to fix that issue:

> Unable to start TM, no active tx log file found but found either
>   tm_tx_log.1 or tm_tx_log.2 file, please set one of them as active or
>   remove them.