# Neo4j not starting after reboot. Unable to start TM, active tx log file

Tags: database, neo4j, recovery

I am running neo4j v 2.1.6 and after maintenance, the server restarted but the neo4j did not.

I was looking at the messages.log and I found there is a file that is not found.

```
2015-03-18 23:52:37.331+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2015-03-18 23:52:37.336+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2015-03-18 23:52:37.340+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2015-03-18 23:52:37.345+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore hit=0 miss=9 switches=0 ooe=0
2015-03-18 23:52:37.349+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.x.NeoStoreXaDataSource]: NeoStore closed
2015-03-18 23:52:37.349+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2015-03-18 23:52:37.349+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2015-03-18 23:52:37.349+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@1321ed47' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Unable to start TM, active tx log file[/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/graph.db/index/0000755000015301777760000000000012436452331013171 5] not found.
2015-03-18 23:52:37.349+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started
2015-03-18 23:52:37.350+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase]: Failed to start database.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:45) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:119) ~[neo4j-server-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:186) [neo4j-server-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:109) [neo4j-server-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:63) [neo4j-server-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@1321ed47' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to start TM, active tx log file[/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/graph.db/index/0000755000015301777760000000000012436452331013171 5] not found.
```

How can I recover the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException in Neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586697/org-neo4j-kernel-lifecycle-lifecycleexception-in-neo4j)

Comment: we noticed that the paths in your stacktrace are inconsistent some are `/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/...` the last one is `/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/graph.db/...`. Are you aware of any setup inconsistencies? Can you share your full messages log somewhere?

Comment: yes, i realized about that, but we didnt change anything in the server configuration.  Do you know how to fix the path? i can send you the entire messages.log via email

Comment: please send it to michael at neo4j.org did you upgrade the database version in between?

Comment: how did you shut down the database and how did you move the database directory?

Comment: i just stopped the service and create a copy of the graph.db dir then try to start the service again and it fails.  I just sent you the messages.log file. thx

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after reviewing the messages.log file, [Michael] found something wrong with the active_tx_log file, it must be only 11B; so, i just replace the active_tx_log file and it is working fine now.